# Pivot Table- Add Percent of the Grand Total

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add a calculated filed of percent participation in my Pivot Table using vba. So I want something like this:

| Items | Sum of Points | Percent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | 4 | 40% |
| Second | 3 | 30% |
| Third | 3 | 30% |
| Total | 10 | 100 % |

I thought there is a build in formula and tried to something like this:

```
 With ptt
    .CalculatedFields.Add name:="value", Formula:=xlPercentOf
    .PivotFields("value").Orientation = xlDataField
    .PivotFields("Sum of value").name = "Percent"
    .PivotFields("Prercent").NumberFormat = "0.00%"
 End With
```

But i got the same percent value in every row, so its not what I wanted. I will be greatful for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying recording macro while creating % with pivot:

[image]

and it returns its script that can hint you some things:

```
   ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable3").PivotFields("Points"), "Sum of Points2", xlSum    
   With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Sum of Points2")
        .Caption = "Percent"
        .Calculation = xlPercentOfTotal
        .NumberFormat = "0.00%"
    End With
```

Comment: You are welcome @Aleksandra, yeah recoding macro is a powerful thing for scripting application built functions (most of the cases).

Answer (score 0):

i think it needs you to specify xlCount in addition to the xlPercentOfTotal.
i tried navafolk's answer and got an error, but the following modifications worked for me...

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("KPIPivotTable").PivotFields("KPI")
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Function = xlCount
    .Calculation = xlPercentOfTotal
    .NumberFormat = "0.00%"
    .Name = "Percent of Total"
End With
```